# 400 (Bad Request) - When updating value in AngularJS

Tags: .net, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

I keep getting a 400 Bad Request when trying to update the reputation-field of my application. What it's supposed to do is to save the value once the reputation has been increased or decreased. It recognizes the id of the post so that shouldn't be a problem. Note that I'm very new to AngularJS so I this may be very easy, but I have no idea.

Here's the backend:

```
// PUT api/Post/5
        public IHttpActionResult PutPost(int id, Post post)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != post.pid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!PostExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
```

The function:

```
$scope.increment = function (post) {
    post.reputation += 1;
    Post.update({ id: post.pid });
}
```

The factory:

```
droppeApp.factory('Post', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/Post/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' },
        delete: { method: 'DELETE' }
    });
});
```

And the items from the view:

```
<span class="decrease right" ng-click="decrease(post);">-</span>
<span class="increment right" ng-click="increment(post);">+</span>
```

Comment: What happens if you put `[HttpPut]` attribute on the method `public IHttpActionResult PutPost(int id, Post post)`? It may be that you need to specifically declare that the method accepts PUT requests. Bit of a guess though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to be passing the resource object itself as the second argument to `Post.update`:

```
Post.update({id: post.id}, post);
```

IIRC you should also be able to just do:

```
post.update();
```

Take a look at the [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) docs and scroll down to the bit about creating a custom put request.